# Change order in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a little problem ...
I want to make a column have ordered some data,
like this...

[image]

and when I made a form to edit it, I can change the order as I want without repeat any number in this order ...

like I want here .. I want change order test3 to 1 so the result will be

[image]

this my controller update code

```
$order_id = Section::where('section_id', $request->section_id)->get();
$edit_order=$order_id[0]['section_order'];

$request_order=$request->section_order;


for ($i = $request_order; $i <= $edit_order ; $i++) {

    $siction_data = Section::where('section_order', $i)->get();
    $edit_siction_id=$siction_data[0]['section_id'];
    $edit_siction_order=$siction_data[0]['section_order']+1;


if ($siction_data[0]['section_order']===$edit_order) {
    $edit_siction_order=(int)$request_order;
}

$update_data= array(
    'section_order' => $edit_siction_order,
);

Section::where('section_id', $edit_siction_id)->update($update_data);

}
```

But nothing happens...

plz help me or even you have better code to make the process faster special when I want to change order test1000 to 1

Comment: Surely you don't need to be updating the `name`, `pic`, `id` etc because all you want to update is the `section_order`?

Comment: yes , you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple logic for that:

Suppose x is the new order that you want to assign to the item.
We have two scenarios:

1. If x is less than the current order of the item.

In this case, you just increment the order field of all other rows where order is greater than or equal to x. Then assign x as the order for the item.

2. If x is less than current order of the item.

Here, you decrement the order field of all other rows where order is less than or equal to x. And then assign x as order for the item.

```
$order_id = Section::where('section_id', $request->section_id)->first();
$key = $order_id->getKey();

$edit_order=$order_id->section_order;
$request_order=$request->section_order;

if($request_order< $edit_order){

    Section::where('section_order','>=',$request_order)
        ->where('section_order','<',$edit_order)
        ->update([
            'section_order' => DB::Raw('section_order + 1')
        ]);

}else{
    Section::where('section_order','<=',$request_order)
        ->where('section_order','>',$edit_order)
        ->update([
            'section_order' => DB::Raw('section_order - 1')
        ]);   

}

Section::find($key)->update([
    'section_order' => $request_order
]);
```

EDIT: How to re-assign section_order column with continuos integers

Assuming that id is the primary key of your Section model.

```
$subQuery = Section::orderBy('section_order')
                ->selectRaw('id, @re_order := (CASE WHEN @re_order IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @re_order END) + 1 re_order')
                ->getQuery();

        Section::joinSub($subQuery, 'reOrderTable', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('reOrderTable.id', '=', 'sections.id');
                })
                ->update([
                    'sections.section_order' => DB::raw('`re_order`')
        ]);
```

Comment: DB::Raw .. it's give me error (Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\DB'.)

Comment: i correct DB error and run the code .. but it give me another error  id is null... Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `sections` set `section_order` = 1, `sections`.`updated_at` = 2020-01-10 12:53:36 where `id` is null)

Comment: Are you getting a Section instance from $order_id = Section::where('section_id', $request->section_id)->first();? Or is it null?

Comment: when i change last code ( $order_id->update(['section_order' => $request_order]); ) To ( Section::where('section_id',$order_id)->update(['section_order' =>$request_order]); ) it's work

Comment: but the the section i want to edit first don't update it's the same order not change

Comment: thank you a lot for you help me your code work fine with me .. thanks again :)

Comment: can you help my plz , i have a problem when i delete one or more section at once the order between sections it change , i want to sort column 'section_order' asc and update all sections order by 1-2-3-... at once , thank you

Comment: I have added a code snippet  how to re-assign section_order column with continous numbers starting from 1. Run that code after you delete any rows.

Comment: it's give error ....  ( Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `sections` inner join (select id, @re_order := (CASE WHEN @re_order IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @re_order END) + 1 re_order from `sections` order by `section_order` asc) as `reOrderTable` on `reOrderTable`.`id` = `sections`.`id` set `sections`.`section_order` = `re_order`, `sections`.`updated_at` = 2020-01-16 12:10:42))

Comment: my table name is 'sections' ... and i have 6 column 'section_id' , 'section_order' , 'section_name' , 'section_pic' , 'created_at' , 'updated_at'

Comment: change "id" to "section_id" if that is your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The function `.get()` returns an array of collection object not arrays so you need to treat them that way. Also there are simpler way to do what you are trying to do. It's better to use `.first()` if you want to extract one element and lose the [0]:

```
$order_id = Section::where('section_id', $request->section_id)->first();
$edit_order=$order_id->section_order;

$request_order=$request->section_order;


for ($i = $request_order; $i <= $edit_order ; $i++) {
    $siction_data = Section::where('section_order', $i)->first();    
    if ($siction_data->section_order===$edit_order) {
        $edit_siction_order=(int)$request_order;
    }else{
        $edit_siction_order= (int)$siction_data->section_order + 1
    }

    $siction_data->section_order=$edit_siction_order;
    $siction_data->save();
}
```

From your error about `id` column, it seems that you have `section_id` as your primary key to make Laravel know that you need to specify it in your model:

```
class Section extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey  = 'section_id';
    //the rest of your model code
}
```

Comment: I've updated answer so that it handles the if statement.

Comment: the error ( Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `sections` set `section_order` = 2, `sections`.`updated_at` = 2020-01-10 16:02:13 where `id` is null) )

Comment: your table does not have an id column?

Comment: Laravel always assume that you have an `id` column, unless you say otherwise. Check the last part of my updated answer to see how.

Comment: thank you for your help i miss ( protected $primaryKey  = 'section_id';) so it work fine now .. thanks again :)